# AS3 -sort array values and take average of ones in the middle

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, sorting

Trying to create the AS3 equivalent of both median and averaging filters.

An averaging filter would simply be getting the average values of an array's contents.

How would I first sort an array of say length 10, and then get the average of the 5 middle values?

Comment: How much detail do you need? take a look at the Array sort method. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have an `Array` (or [`Vector`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html)) of numbers:

Use `sort()` with `Array.NUMERIC`:

```
numbers.sort(Array.NUMERIC);
```

Use `slice()` to copy a sub-set of the sorted array:

```
var middleIndex:int = numbers.length / 2;
var middleNumbers:Array = numbers.slice(middleIndex - 2, middleIndex + 2);
```

Write a function which uses a `for` loop to iterate over the elements and sum them, then divide the sum by the array's length:

```
function average(numbers:Array):Number {
    var sum:Number = 0;
    for each(var n:Number in numbers){
        sum += n;
    }
    return sum / numbers.length;
}
```

For the median, you want the middle number if the length is odd, or the average of the two middle numbers if the length is even:

```
function median(numbers:Array):Number {
    var middle:Number = numbers.length / 2;
    if(middle is int){
        return numbers[middle];
    }else{
        return (numbers[int(middle)] + numbers[int(middle) + 1]) / 2;
    }
}
```